# The WKWebView was invalidated" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=The WKWebView was invalidated

Tags: swift, wkwebview

I am trying to retrieve html using webView. I don't want to write my webView code in the view file therefore trying to implement it in a different class. Below is my code.

```
class BlobHelper: NSObject,WKNavigationDelegate{

    let webView = WKWebView()

    func getLyrics(){


        let url = URL(string: "https://Blob")!
        let request = URLRequest(url: url)
         webView.load(request)
        webView.evaluateJavaScript("document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0].innerHTML;", completionHandler: {(value,error)in
            print(value)
            print(error)
        })
    }
    func webView(_ webView: WKWebView,didFinish navigation: WKNavigation!) { print("loaded") }
```

When I execute the code I get `Optional(Error Domain=WKErrorDomain Code=3 "The WKWebView was invalidated" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=The WKWebView was invalidated})`.

What I tried
I was able to retrieve html using static but couldn't get the didFinish to call after loading.
Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, WKNavigationDelegate {

var webView = WKWebView()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    let configuration = WKWebViewConfiguration()
    self.webView = WKWebView(frame: .zero, configuration: configuration)
    webView.navigationDelegate = self
    let url = URL(string: "https://stackoverflow.com")!
               let request = URLRequest(url: url)
               webView.load(request)
    
    self.view = webView
    
}

func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didFinish navigation: WKNavigation!) {
    webView.evaluateJavaScript("document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0].innerHTML;", completionHandler: { (value,error)in
        
           print(value)
    })
    
}}
```

Comment: check now hope you find the answer.

Comment: I tried your answer however it looks like didFinish is not called. (       `webView.load(request)`) is called

Comment: than you are not connected with Delegate

Comment: however I do have `webView.navigationDelegate = self`

Comment: <key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
    <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
    <true/>
</dict>

Comment: Note that BlobHelper is a struct.

Comment: oh mate you need extend UIView or UIViewController but not NSObject.

Comment: I have inherited UIView but getting the same error... (tried with UIViewController aswell)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/206994/discussion-between-satsuki-and-ayaz-akbar).

Comment: let configuration = WKWebViewConfiguration()

Comment: let webView = WKWebView(frame: .zero, configuration: configuration)